# Is there an easier way of updating nested arrays in react-native (react-redux)?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am trying to update an array inside of my array (nested array) with react-redux. I found a solution to how to do this but is there any easier way of doing this rather than passing multiple parameter to the action.

```
[types.HISTORY_UPDATE](state, action){
  return { 
    ...state, 
    budgets: [
       ...state.budgets.slice(0,action.id),
       {
        key: action.key,
        id: action.idd,
        name: action.name,
        budgetType: action.budgetType,
        startDate: action.startDate,
        currency: action.currency,
        amount: action.amount,
        amountLeft: action.amountLeft,
        rollOver: action.rollOver,
        color: action.color,
        iconName: action.iconName,
        history: [
          ...state.budgets[action.id].history.slice(0,action.histId),
          {
            note: action.note,
           amount: action.amount,
            type: action.type,
            date: action.date,
            fullDate: action.fullDate,
            hours: action.hours,
            min: action.min,
            month: action.month,
            year: action.year
          },
          ...state.budgets[action.id].history.slice(action.histId+1)
      ]

    },
      ...state.budgets.slice(action.id+1)
      ]
 }
},
```

and the action goes like this

```
export function updateHistory(id,key,idd,name,budgetType,startDate,currency,amount,amountLeft,rollOver,color,iconName,histId,........){
```

I don't want to spend time with passing multiple parameter like this while using react-redux and also while I tried to run my application on my phone sometimes it really slows the application. Is it because of the example above?

I would be really appreciated If you guys come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically do not store arrays in redux, since updating a single element really is a burden as you noticed. If the objects you have inside your array all have a unique id, you can easily convert that array to an object of objects. As key for each object you take that id.

```
const convertToObject = (array) => {
    let items = {};

    array.map((item) => {
      items[item.id] = item;
    });

    return items;
  };
```

In your action you simply just pass the item you want to update as payload, and you can update the redux store very easily. In this example below I am just updating the budgets object, but the same logic applies when you assign a history object to each budget.

```
[types.BUDGET_UPDATE](state, action){

  const item = action.payload;

  return {
    ...state,
    budgets: {
      ...state.budgets,
      [item.id]: item
    }   
  }
}
```

And if you want an array somewhere in your component code, you just convert the redux store object back to an array:

```
const array = Object.values(someReduxStoreObject);
```

Comment: and also I have one more question. Does the way I do update operation make my application slower only on real devices or there might be other problems?

Comment: Updating an object will definitely be faster, since there is no need to loop over an array. In case of nesting the difference increases. In general I would not recommend arrays in the redux store, unless you are certain they do not grow too big.